# Appending child node by javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, dom

I have dynamically generated html thru ajax when a page is loading, something like this,

#### Dynamically inserted,

```
<p class="Hello">
  <span id='click lvl1'>1</span>
  <span>2</span>
</p>
```

Now, I am trying to add another node into my `<p>` element. Again, dynamically thru ajax.

#### Server response is something like,

```
<p class="Hello lvl2">
  <span id='click'>1</span>
  <span>2</span>
</p>
```

Which I want to insert into the element which I have got first time.

#### final result,

```
<p class="Hello">
  <span id='click'>1</span>
  <span>2</span>
  <p class="Hello lvl2">
   <span id='click'>1</span>
   <span>2</span>
  </p>
</p>
```

While making an ***second*** ajax call I am getting reference to `<span id='click lvl1'>1</span>` element.

---

#### What have I tried so far?

Everthing, I could try I have tried but I am not able to inset the node. I am assuming that I am doing something really wrong. My attempts are,

#### pElement is `<span id='click'>1</span>`

1. `pElement.parent().appendChild(data.expandTreeVal);`
2. `pElement.parent().append(data.expandTreeVal);`
3. `pElement.parent().after(data.expandTreeVal);`
4. `pElement.parentNode().appendChild(data.expandTreeVal);`

### Debugging

Do I really get anything from server?

Yes, When I do `alert(data.expandTreeVal);` it shows me my desired HTML.

any thoughts will be a great help.

Comment: I think you can use, .prepend() function it should work i suppose.

Comment: debug `pElement`, does it reference the element that you've dynamically added to the page or the API response before adding it to the page. Then debug `pElement.parent()` to make sure you're selecting the correct element.

Comment: `<p>` elements can't have `<p>` children.

Comment: @zzzzBov, A very good point! Thanks, Sorry I am from Objective C and Java and getting my feet wet by learning scripting lang :)

Comment: Also, `[id]` attributes need to be unique, you should be using `[class]` attributes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only append DOM elements to an element, you can't append HTML code in a string.

Create an element, use the `innerHTML` method to put the HTML code in it, then get the first child node from it to get the `p` element as a DOM element.

```
var div = document.createElement('DIV');
div.innerHTML = data.expandTreeVal;
var p = div.childNodes[0];
```

Then you can add it to the document using the `parentNode` and `appendChild` methods:

```
pElement.parentNode.appendChild(p);
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/AfVfE/

Comment: That worked like a charm, However I missed a good point that I should not add <p> inside a <p> as OP mentioned. But thanks for the enlightenment about what to do.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to post a full blown use case for me to fully understand, but I think that the whole issue is that you're referencing methods that don't exist.

My use case worked fine like this:

```
<p class="Hello">
  <span id='click'>1</span>
  <span>2</span>
  <p class="Hello lvl2">
   <span id='click'>1</span>
   <span>2</span>
  </p>
</p>
```

With this JS:

```
​var pElement = document.getElementById('click');
alert(pElement.parentNode);​​​
```

​